# How do I update glassfish 4.1.1 inside netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, ide, netbeans-8, glassfish-4.1

I am working on a tutorial using glassfish inside netbeans https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/setup.html . I reached this point in the tutorial (Don't mind the Pool name, I changed it to fit my own) [image: Tutorial]

But when I click next I get this error [image: error]

I read on the internet that some people say this error occurs cause there is a bug in glassfish version 4.1.1 but when I try to update glassfish from inside Netbeans [image]

And I click yes then I get this error [image: error2] [image]

It doesn't help either if I go into the glassfish admin area and click on Update tool [image: update tool]

Cause no Items show up even though there have been updates since and glassfish is now on version 5.0. I by the way checked if I was behind a proxy here http://amibehindaproxy.com/ and I wasn't and my internet speed showed this [image]

So is there anybody who can tell me what I do wrong??? There are some other post about the subject but non of the solutions helped me.

Answer (score 5):

The Update Center in GlassFish no longer works because the server it tries to connect to does not exist any more after Oracle ended commercial support. To update GlassFish you will need to:

- [Download GlassFish separately](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/glassfish/download)
- Unzip it to a location of your choice
- Add it to netbeans manually by right-clicking "servers" and choosing "Add Server"

If you are concerned about bugs in GlassFish, you may want to try [Payara Server, which is derived from GlassFish](https://www.payara.fish/downloads) but has many more bug fixes. (Payara Server has the same free, open source license as GlassFish)